# How is Amazon EKS-vended version of kubectl different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, amazon-eks

I noticed that on [Installing kubectl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html) documentation page, AWS offers a "EKS-vended" version of `kubectl`.

I'm currently using GKE and I already have `kubectl` installed that is part of Google Cloud SDK. I plan to start new workload on EKS, can I use the GCP version of `kubectl` instead of AWS version? How are they different?

**Update:**
I just saw on the guide that it is identical to the `kubectl` community version. I have missed that part earlier

> These binaries are identical to the upstream community versions, and
>   are not unique to Amazon EKS or AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EKS supports specific versions of Kubernetes and you can find the versions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html

You should be using the Kubectl client corresponding to the EKS version.

As long as you are using a matching kubectl client version, it works.

I find it easier to install the kubectl distributed by EKS since I don't need to worry about versioning issues. As well as, I can all ways lookup the AWS docs to get started without any other dependencies.

If you are alternating between GCP & EKS or using different Kubernetes versions, you can consider installing kubectl to a local folder.

Comment: I just saw on the documentation page that it's identical to the community version, not sure how I have missed it earlier. Anyways, great suggestion about installing `kubectl` to a local folder